# Apache error: Cannot load modules/mod_actions.so into server: The specified module could not be found

Tags: php, apache, server, syntax-error

I am trying to run a PHP app and I downloaded Apache to run a local server but I keep getting this error:

```
Cannot load modules/mod_actions.so into server: The specified module could not be found.
```

Does anyone know what might be going on? And how would I solve this?

Many thanks :))